# How to route all traffic from single contrainer via another container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to route all traffic from one single container via one other container. I found tutorial on how to route all container via host or host via container, but online sources are bit more quiet on my topic.

I have one container `us-vpn` which basically just connect to openvpn. Then I want to have another container `netflix` which routes all traffic via the openvpn.

What I found is `--network container:us-vpn` which is supposed to "share the network stack of another container". Is that what I want?

There is also `network_mode: "service:us-vpn"` in docker-compose, but I did not found any documentation on what it's supposed to do.

Comment: You can use any proxy server(like NGINX) inside the container to redirect the traffic according to request URL from one central container to other containers.

Comment: @graywolf did you or did you not resolve what you were suffering? Could make more communications here for further discussion.

Answer (score 1):

If the `us-vpn` container could access internet as expected, I think yes, it is what you want.

When running a container with `--network container:some-container-id`, that means these containers share the same network namespace. All of these containers’ traffic would be routed to outside by the same network namespace. You may simplify it as these containers use the same network interface to communicate with out world.

So I think the speaking of “route all traffic from a single container via another container” above is not quite precisely.

As `service:[service-name]`(added in version 2 of docker-compose.yaml), unless you deploy with `docker-compose`, you need not deal with it.